# How do I calculate the coverage of an area from point data?

Tags: r

I have several months of data files, each containing 24-hour records of fish x,y,z coordinates in two 25x25x20m fish farm pens for 40 tagged fish where each tag is positioned every 6-9 seconds. Each file contains about 365,000 observations.

I want to calculate the proportion of the pen covered by the fish each day. I have written some R code that does the job, but due to the large file sizes it takes about 4 hours to run. Here is my code:

```
xmin <- 8
ymin <- 11.5
xmax <- 33
ymax <- 36.5
boxsize <- 1

# define coverage grid
cov.grid <- matrix(c(xmin,ymin), nrow = 1, ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE)
colnames(cov.grid) <- c('x','y')
x <- xmin
y <- ymin
while(x < xmax)
  {
  while(y < ymax)
    {
    y <- y+boxsize
    cov.grid <- rbind(cov.grid, c(x,y))  
    }
  x <- x+boxsize
  y <- ymin
  cov.grid <- rbind(cov.grid, c(x,y))  
}
cov.grid <- as.data.frame(cov.grid)


# count grid cells occupied by fish
day.row <- 1
grid.row <- 1
bin <- 0
cov.grid$occupied <- NA

for(grid.row in 1:nrow(cov.grid)){
x1 <- cov.grid[grid.row,1]
y1 <- cov.grid[grid.row,2]
x2 <- x1+boxsize
y2 <- cov.grid[grid.row+1,2] 
repeat
  {
  if(dayfile[day.row,'PosX'] > x1 & dayfile[day.row,'PosX'] < x2 &         dayfile[day.row,'PosY'] > y1 & dayfile[day.row,'PosY'] < y2) {bin <- 1} else    {bin <- 0}
  day.row <- day.row+1
  if(bin == 1 | day.row == nrow(dayfile)){break}
  }
cov.grid[grid.row,'occupied'] <- bin
day.row <- 1
}

# return coverage summary

coverage <- matrix(c(length(which(cov.grid$occupied == 1)), nrow(cov.grid),     length(which(cov.grid$occupied == 1))/nrow(cov.grid)), ncol = 3)
colnames(coverage) <- c('occupied', 'total', 'proportion')
coverage
```

The logic of the code is as follows:

1. Create a matrix grid of the pen area.
2. For each grid cell, look through the fish coordinate file to check if a fish occupies that cell; 1 if yes, 0 if no.
3. Add a new column to the grid matrix to record whether each cell was occupied by a fish.
4. Count the number of occupied cells and calculate the proportion coverage of the pen.

Ideally, I would like the grid resolution to be 0.1m resolution, but even with a 1m resolution it takes 4 hours to run; 25x25m grid array = 625 cells, so the coordinate file of 365,000 fish observations has to be cross tabulated with the grid array 625 times. With a 0.1m grid resolution, the 365,000 observations would need to be cross tabulated 625,000 times, which would probably take several weeks!

I'm sure there must be a more efficient way to do this. However, I've only been learning R for a couple of months now, so I'm not sure how to improve the code.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: You could chop off the edges of your searchspace by first finding the most north, south, east, and west points and directly assigning 0 to anything outside of that. Also, you could start with a fatter resolution and then refine the resolution only for the areas that had a 1 (if there's no fish in the big square, then no reason to check its smaller squares). But the better approach may be to flip your process:  identify each fish's coordinates and then plot them as 1s in your grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use loops at all. The following does the job:

```
compute.coverage <- function(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, boxsize, dayfile) {
  x.grid <- floor((dayfile$PosX - xmin) / boxsize) + 1
  y.grid <- floor((dayfile$PosY - ymin) / boxsize) + 1
  x.grid.max <- floor((xmax - xmin) / boxsize) + 1
  y.grid.max <- floor((ymax - ymin) / boxsize) + 1
  t.x <- sort(unique(x.grid))
  t.y <- sort(unique(y.grid))
  tx.range <- c(min(which(t.x > 0)), max(which(t.x <= x.grid.max)))
  ty.range <- c(min(which(t.y > 0)), max(which(t.y <= y.grid.max)))
  t <- table(y.grid, x.grid)[ty.range[1]:ty.range[2],tx.range[1]:tx.range[2]]
  grid.cov <- matrix(0,nrow=y.grid.max,ncol=x.grid.max)
  t.x <- t.x[(t.x > 0) & (t.x <=x.grid.max)]
  t.y <- t.y[(t.y > 0) & (t.y <=y.grid.max)]
  eg <- expand.grid(t.y,t.x)
  grid.cov[cbind(eg$Var1,eg$Var2)] <- as.vector(t)  
  coverage <- matrix(c(length(which(grid.cov > 0)), length(grid.cov), length(which(grid.cov > 0))/length(grid.cov)), ncol = 3)
  colnames(coverage) <- c('occupied', 'total', 'proportion')
  coverage
}
```

The key to this computation is to compute the grid box location `(x.grid,y.grid)` for each observation as Rufo (the other answer) did. Here, however, this computation is **vectorized** over *all* observations in `dayfile` and its complexity is **independent** of the resolution of the grid! The trick is to then use `table` to count the frequecy of occupation at each combination of `(x.grid,y.grid)`. There are two complicating factors here:

1. The computed `(xgrid,y.grid)` location may be outside your pen `(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax)`.
2. Not all of your grid boxes are occupied so that there may be whole rows and/or columns of the table that are missing counts.

The second issue is not pertinent if you are only interested in the percentage of coverage, but it is relevant if you actually care about which box location is occupied. The above code handles both by:

1. Limiting the table to the range, `tx.range` and `ty.range`, of the pen.
2. Mapping the table (possibly with "holes") back to the full grid of the pen `grid.cov`. Here, `grid.cov` is a matrix of the pen that corresponds to your `cov.grid` variable. Its elements record the number of occupations for the box at the `i`-th row and `j`-th column so this is actually more information than your `occupied`, which only specify whether the box has been occupied (at least once). To detect whether a box has been occupied, we evaluate `grid.cv > 0`.

Running this on a 0.1 meter resolution grid on a `dayfile` with 365,000 simulated observations took less than 2 seconds on my 2 GHz Macbook:

```
xmin <- 8
ymin <- 11.5
xmax <- 33
ymax <- 36.5
boxsize <- 0.1

## simulate dayfile
set.seed(123)
PosX <- runif(365000,xmin-2,xmax+2)
PosY <- runif(365000,ymin-2,ymax+2)
dayfile <- data.frame(PosX=PosX,PosY=PosY)

print(system.time(coverage <- compute.coverage(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,boxsize,dayfile)))
##   user  system elapsed 
##  1.096   0.052   1.193 

print(coverage)
##     occupied total proportion
##[1,]    62168 63001   0.986778
```

Comment: Guys, that is awesome, thanks so much!

I've tried both of your solutions, and they both work great, but aichao's is the quickest as it doesn't use loops. I don't fully understand your code, but I see it depends on the use of the 'floor' and 'table' commands, which I haven't used before, so I will spend some time soon to work through your code so I know what I'm doing for next time. I've now batched the code so it runs through 60 days of data and it takes just a few minutes using my 3.2GHz pc. 

Thanks again for your efforts, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution where you create a matrix with zeros representing the grid and then you add 1 to the cell where each fish is located. Then you distinguish between cells with 1 or more fishes and cells without fishes and finally you do the proportion. I did not check for efficiency, but I guess it will work better (there are no comparisons and only one `for`).

I wrapped the solution inside a function (it is more elegant and can be applied more easily on several occasions)

Tell me if that worked for you, please!

```
dayfile<-data.frame(PosX=c(30.5,25.5,28.5), PosY=c(30,24,20))

xmin <- 8
ymin <- 11.5
xmax <- 33
ymax <- 36.5
boxsize <- 1

coveragefun<-function(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, boxsize, dayfile){

  ncols <- ceiling((xmax-xmin)/boxsize)
  nrows <- ceiling((ymax-ymin)/boxsize)

  matspace <- matrix(0,nrow=nrows, ncol=ncols)

  for(i in 1:(dim(dayfile)[1])){
    xpos <- 1 + (dayfile$PosX[i]-(xmin))/boxsize
    ypos <- 1 + (dayfile$PosY[i]-(ymin))/boxsize
    matspace[xpos,ypos]<-matspace[xpos,ypos]+1
  }

  matcount<-matspace>=1

  coverage <- c(sum(matcount), dim(matcount)[1]*dim(matcount)[2], sum(matcount)/(dim(matcount)[1]*dim(matcount)[2]))
  names(coverage) <- c('occupied', 'total', 'proportion')
  return(coverage)
}

coverageres <- coveragefun(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, boxsize, dayfile)
coverageres
```

You may also recover the matspace object from the function so you can do a summary and know how much populated are the cells in your grid. To do so, you can change the last lines of the code as follows

```
  return(list(coverage, matspace))
}

coverageres <- coveragefun(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, boxsize, dayfile)
coverageres[[1]]
table(coverageres[[2]])
```